# jQuery: trying to use prepend()

Tags: jquery, prepend

I'm trying to use prepend() to put a text before an input text.

This is my try:

http://jsfiddle.net/sx7JW/2/

but it doesn't work..

any idea?

Javi

Comment: You notice that this jsFiddle is set to MooTools? An occasional look into the JavaScript error console of your favorite browser can be very revealing.

Comment: I changed it in my jsfiddle, don't forget to press enter in the field because that is what you wanted right?

Comment: I don't see any code in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use prepend, which adds the given text inside the input is makes your text appear in the input. Something like:

```
<input type='text'>Your text</input>
```

You need to use before which creates

```
Your Text <input type='text'/>
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sx7JW/5/)

You can also do something like this, this adds the text as first item for the parent of the input.

```
$('input').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        console.log($(this));
        $(this).parent().prepend("<p>fasf</p>");
        alert('You pressed enter!');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You set it to mootools not jquery
2. What you  need is before() not prepend().

http://jsfiddle.net/sx7JW/9/